Using Option<String>, and other non-implementers of Display, with askama::Template
I'd like to use identical struct for receiving data from sqlx and for passing that data into an askama::Template.  (I will have many such structs.)
sqlx makes me use Option<String> as the column is a nullable varchar.
askama::Template forbids me using Option<String> as it requires the Display trait.
If I try to derive an askama::Template from a struct which contains an Option<String> I get the error:
error[E0277]: `std::option::Option<std::string::String>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/root.rs:35:10
   |
35 | #[derive(Template)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^ `std::option::Option<std::string::String>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`, which is required by `&std::option::Option<std::string::String>: std::fmt::Display`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args` which comes from the expansion of the derive macro `Template` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

How can I use one struct for both purposes?
This is my current work-around, using two similar structs and an implementation of From:
use askama::Template;
use axum::{extract::Query, Extension};
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use serde::Deserialize;
use sqlx::PgPool;
//use tracing::debug;

#[derive(sqlx::FromRow, Debug)]
pub struct LatestProvisioningRequest {
    uid: String,
    ts: DateTime<Utc>,
    ip: Option<String>,
}

pub struct LatestProvisioningRequestForTemplate {
    uid: String,
    ts: DateTime<Utc>,
    ip: String,
}

impl From<LatestProvisioningRequest> for LatestProvisioningRequestForTemplate {
    fn from(value: LatestProvisioningRequest) -> Self {
        let ip = match value.ip {
            Some(str) => str,
            None => "".to_owned(),
        };
        LatestProvisioningRequestForTemplate {
            uid: value.uid,
            ts: value.ts,
            ip
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Template)]
#[template(path = "root.html")]
pub struct RootTemplate {
    requests: Vec<LatestProvisioningRequestForTemplate>
}

// Used to extract the "next" field from the query string.
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct RootQueryParameters {
    // TODO
}

pub async fn fetch_unenrolled(pool: &PgPool) -> Vec<LatestProvisioningRequestForTemplate> {
    let rows = sqlx::query_as::<_, LatestProvisioningRequest>(r#"SELECT * FROM latest_provisioning_requests"#)
    .fetch_all(pool)
    .await
    .unwrap();

    rows.into_iter().map(|x| x.into()).collect()
}

pub async fn root(
    Extension(pool): Extension<PgPool>,
    Query(RootQueryParameters {}): Query<RootQueryParameters>
) -> RootTemplate {

    RootTemplate {
        requests: fetch_unenrolled(&pool).await
    }
}


When you can't derive a trait, the usual workaround is to implement it.

@cafce25 While I could impl Display for LatestProvisioningRequest that still wouldn't make Option<String> implement Display.  I cannot implement Display on Option<String> because both are defined outside this module.  Next, I will test my assumption that manually implementing Display with cause the error to next report the issue with Option<String> not implementing Display.

I wasn't talking about Display but either of FromRow or Template I guess FromRow is easier in this particular instance.

@cafce25 Could that be done in fewer lines of code than having two structs (as per the workaround)?

I don't get why implementing Display for LatestProvisioningRequest would error unless you're trying to use a display implementation of Option<String> though, you can easily write!(f, "{}", ip.as_deref().unwrap_or(""))

Why the obsession with "fewer lines of code"? Thats seldomly useful.

@cafce25 My assumption is that Askama template rendering uses the Display trait and that that causes the requirement for Display.  I will test this later today.

@cafce25 Apologies, "fewer lines of code" is just a clumsy way of saying that I don't want a solution that is more complex and more difficult to understand than the existing work-around.

Just to keep everything simple, let's assume we have the following struct Page:
use askama::Template;

#[derive(Template, Clone, Debug)]
#[template(path = "page.html.jinja")]
pub struct Page {
    text: Option<String>,
}

Now we want to always render text if it's Some or render nothing if it's None.

This can be done in a few ways, e.g. using if let:
{% if let Some(text) = self.text %}
    {{ text }}
{% endif %}

You can also use a match:
{% match self.text %}
    {% when Some with (text) %}
        {{ text }}
    {% else %}
{% endmatch %}

Alternatively, you can also go all in and use if, .is_some(), and .unwrap():
{% if self.text.is_some() %}
    {{ self.text.as_ref().unwrap() }}
{% endif %}


However, the solution I personally prefer, is using a custom filter:
mod filters {
    pub fn display_some<T>(value: &Option<T>) -> askama::Result<String>
    where
        T: std::fmt::Display,
    {
        Ok(match value {
            Some(value) => value.to_string(),
            None => String::new(),
        })
    }
}

Note, this intentionally uses &Option<T>, instead of Option<T> or Option<&T>, as Askama auto references arguments.
The mod filters must be in the same module as your template(s).
{{ self.text|display_some }}

If you have Option<Thing> where Thing doesn't implement fmt::Display, then you can manually implement fn display_thing(thing: &Option<Thing>) that handles rendering it.

Instead of a filter, you can also use a normal function instead:
pub fn display_some<T>(value: &Option<T>) -> String
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    match value {
        Some(value) => value.to_string(),
        None => String::new(),
    }
}

{{ self::display_some(self.text) }}

This assumes that display_some() is in the same module as your template(s).

Lastly, you can also do the following. But it's a bit more ugly, and only works for any T that can deref into &str:
{{ self.text.as_deref().unwrap_or("") }}

